# Large array implode inside mysql IN clause shows error because of length

Tags: php, mysql

This is the query which is giving me an error. If I run this code in the local server it's working fine. But in my live server its showing error. I think this error is related to server configuration, hence I have increased max_allowed_packet option of my live server. But still getting the same error

```
 $dueClassification = "
    SELECT installmentNo,collection_date,lastInstallmentDate,sales_date,sales_bill_no,installment_amount,pay_amount,total_sales_amount 
    FROM collection 
    WHERE  sales_type =2 AND collection_date <= '$endDate' 
        AND sales_bill_no IN ('" . implode("','", $currentPeriodSalesBillNoArr) . "')";
```

Comment: remove single quote in IN condition and try

Comment: Seeing the error would be helpful. "Do not use IN for lists longer than you would type by hand" - quite a sensible rule of thumb. I think You might have to do this one a different way; batch it or upload your array values to a table and use join

Comment: Are you sure you need to pass the `IN` list as a literal list? If the list is coming from another query, you can do it as a join between the queries.

Comment: Join will not be efficient since the tables contain many columns.. this is the reason I have ignored join

Answer (score 0):

As per the [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in), the number of values in the IN list is only limited by parameter [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet).

You can try and increase the size of this parameter (it defaults to 64 Mb and has a max value of 1Go).

When this approach is defeated, the next option is to use a JOIN query. This might even be faster, as you will execute just one query instead of two in your current implementation (with php processing in between). The exact syntax depends on how you recover the list - you did not show us that part of the code.

NB : if the values in the list are numbers, you should not quote the arguments of the IN clause ; this will not necessarily resolve the list size issue (especially if numbers are small), but it it will make your query more efficient.